# Golang - threads automatically suspends in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, go

I've tried to parallelize some calculations for range of uint32 using all CPU cores on my Raspberry PI 2:

```
...
numcpu := runtime.NumCPU()
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(numcpu) //4 cores
c := make(chan int, numcpu) //buffered channel
results := make([]int, numcpu)
part := math.MaxUint32/numcpu

for i:=0; i<numcpu; i++ {
    go calculate(c,i*part,(i+1)*part,i)
}
for i:=0; i<numcpu; i++ {
    results = append(results,<-c)
}
...

func calculate(c chan int, from, to, i int) {
    ... //calculating result
    c<-result
    println("Goroutine #", i, " stopped") //just for debug
}
```

But during execution *[htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnlS3.png)* shows me that program has 4 subthreads. One of them has no processing time and others are suspended. Could it be that all goroutines migrated to main thread? If it is, how can I prevent it?

Update:

When I cross-compiled binary by the Windows using gox, the problem was solved, despite the fact that performance has rapidly decreased.
But why when I using binary built by *go build* on my RaspPI these subthreads are suspending?

Update:

After updating from standard `apt-get`ed golang v1.03 for Debian Wheezy to **golang v1.5** the problems seems to be solved (despite the fact that *all.bash* cgo-tests was failed). Thank you all for optimization tips. I'm beginner in golang and don't know much about version-specific optimization.
But if you still want to inspect code: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kzuJJX3c)

Comment: You'll likely get more help if you post the full program, so others can try/debug it.

Comment: Not your main issue, but when you are collecting the results into `results` I  don’t think you need `append`, just do `results[i] = <-c`, otherwise you end up with `numcpu` zeros at the beginning of `results`. You’ve already made `results` big enough in the call to `make`.

Comment: the program run too fast for htop, i think. you can print nanoseconds in your function to check the `parallelize `

Comment: Nitpick: `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(numcpu)` is pre Go1.5 and even then it was considered a bad habit.